# Sorting DataGridView by Hidden Column

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `BindingSource` that is bound to a `DataSet`. For most of the columns, the default sort order is fine, but for one of the columns, the displayed data isn't good for sorting and I have a hidden calculated column, `SortCol` in the `DataSet` to make a better sort for that column.

The problem is, `SortCompare`, where I have code to redirect the sort to `SortCol` doesn't get called. I've been Googling this for a couple hours, and it seems like everyone says that `SortCompare` isn't used when the `DataSource` property is set on the `DataGridView` - it expects the bound `DataSource` to perform the sort - and then the topic is dropped, without any advice on how you can actually perform the sort.

I've looked in the `BindingSource` and the `DataSet`, and I'm not seeing any exposed interfaces for doing custom sorting. I'm all set to derive my own `BindingSource` to do it, but I'm hoping there's a way that's less of a headache to do what should be a lot more straightforward.

EDIT: As there appears to be some confusion, I want to clarify that I am not asking how to perform an initial set on the `DataSet` or even on the `DataGridView`. That is trivial. I am specifically asking how I can link clicking on one column header to sorting based on another column (or more generally by other criteria).

I am now working on seeing if I can get it working with `Programmatically` set as the `SortMode`, as the easy way appears to not exist.

UPDATE: No dice - using one `Sort` overload puts the `SortGlyph` on the hidden column, the other gives an error: `DataGridView control is data-bound. The control cannot use the comparer to perform the sort operation.`

UPDATE: Unless you set the `SortGlyph` *after* sorting by the other column. I guess that's the solution I'm going to have to go with; though I think I will leave this open in case someone else comes up with a better answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I finally used for this was to set the `SortMode` to `Programmatic` and handle the 'ColumnHeaderMouseClick' event as follows:

```
    Private Sub DG_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DG.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
        If DG.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is NonSortColumn Then
            Select Case NonSortColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection
                Case SortOrder.Ascending
                    DG.Sort(SortColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
                    NonSortColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending
                Case Else
                    DG.Sort(SortColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    NonSortColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

It still feels like a bit of a kludge compared to just handling the `SortCompare` event or an equivalent from the `BindingSource` or `DataSet`, but at least it seems to be working.